# Use for the '?' character in Python?

Tags: python

Is there some use for the `?` character in Python? I get an invalid syntax error when using it in variable names. Is there some syntax where it is valid?

Unfortunately, what I can find on Google is mostly people asking how to implement the `?` operator from C, which is a different question.

Comment: Did you think to look in the language documentation? The index has a [section on symbols](https://docs.python.org/3/genindex-Symbols.html), note that ? is not there.

Comment: Ternary if in `C` type language yes, but python uses `a if x else b`

Comment: [I’m pretty sure it’s not part of the language.](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html) (Is that what you were asking?)

Comment: @U2744SNOWFLAKE why reopen the question? It's off topic for the site not having an actual programming problem right?

Comment: @jamylak: Well, if it’s straightforward to a few people that it’s asking whether Python uses the `?` character at all, it seems on topic to me.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I didn't find the symbol section you linked to. I noticed that putting '?' in a variable name resulted in a syntax error, but I I didn't dig deep enough to find the reason. The section you linked to doesn't really explain anything about the `?`, but I suppose one could infer that it's not used because of that.

Comment: @U2744SNOWFLAKE, yeah, that's what I'm asking. I was pretty sure it had no use (having never seen it in years of programming in python) but I wasn't sure if if was just something very obscure. Fortunately some answers below seem pretty definitive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#delimiters):

> The following printing ASCII characters are not used in Python. Their occurrence outside string literals and comments is an unconditional error:
>
> $       ?

So no, there isn't really a use for `?` in Python.

Answer (score 2):

No it's not a part of the language.

> The following printing ASCII characters are not used in Python. Their occurrence outside string literals and comments is an unconditional error:
>
> $       ?